# Slicing one column from a NumPy array with datatype?

Tags: python, numpy

I have constructed a `NumPy` array and filled it with data:

```
data = np.zeros(ndata,dtype=[('datetime',np.dtype(np.datetime64)),\
    ('Value','<f8'),('Weight','<f8')])
```

However, now I want to do things like returning just the `datetime` 'column' or just the values. But this isn't a `2D` `NumPy` array. This is a `1D` array of some custom `dtype`, so I can't do for example:

```
data[:,0]
```

I assume this is trivial or I've fundamentally got the wrong idea about how to use `NumPy` arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A numpy datatype can be accessed just like a dictionary, so you can just do:

```
data[0]['datetime']
```

To get the datetime field of row zero or

```
data[:]['datetime']
```

To get an array of the datetime field for all rows.

Comment: Oh great, I was hoping the answer was something as trivial as this. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Often in python you can just try the easiest thing you can think of and it will work :)